# Quarantine for Foreigners in Costa Rica

Tags: covid-19, costa-rica

According to https://ticotimes.net/2020/03/16/costa-rica-declares-state-of-emergency-due-to-coronavirus-will-close-borders-to-foreigners-and-non-residents :

"The country will shut down its borders to foreigners and non-residents starting 11:59 p.m. on Wednesday, March 18. The restriction applies to the country’s ports of entry via land, air or sea.
Starting immediately, citizens and residents who arrive in Costa Rica will be subjected to a mandatory 14-day quarantine"

My flight is arriving on Wednesday March 18th at 10 p.m. Hence the restriction of "border shutdown" will not apply to me. Will the 14 day quarantine apply? 
According to the article it should not, but can someone who has traveled to Costa Rica recently or is familiar with the current quarantine situation please verify.

Comment: @Peter Chikov So you think they’ll quarantine citizens and residents, but not tourists? Are you sure your flight will even depart? All it would take would be a delay of 2 hours (not impossible in the current emergency situation) and you’d not be allowed entry.

Comment: I’m also trying to find an answer to this question. What exactly does quarantine mean? Home quarantine? Or...?

Comment: Slightly more information in https://www.presidencia.go.cr/comunicados/2020/03/gobierno-declara-estado-de-emergencia-nacional-impide-llegada-de-extranjeros-y-se-suspende-lecciones-en-todos-los-centros-educativos-del-pais/

Comment: You haven't said where you're travelling from. Consider the possibility that you will be required to self-isolate on your return. Is travelling still attractive?

Comment: **DO NOT TRAVEL**

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.